# Getting all photos included in a single facebook feed post with either Graph API or FQL?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm using the Facebook graph API to get my recent posts and feed items with "graph.facebook.com/me/feed".  The problem I am having is when a feed object is a post with multiple photos, the data in the results only contains info for one of the photos, and I cant seem to find a way to get the other photos included in the post.

Some details from the feed object:

```
"type": "photo" 
"status_type": "mobile_status_update"
"picture": "http://the_url_to_the_one_photo_it_does_return.jpg" 
"message": "The message/note attached with the photos for the post",
"id": "xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx" 
"object_id": "yyyyyyyyyyyyy"
```

I tried sending the "id" (post id) through a request (graph.facebook.com/xxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx), hoping it would give me the details of all the photos included in the post, but it does not.  Also tried with "object_id" but it looks like that is just the id corresponding to the single included photo object.

I spent all day researching FQL.  It is still new to me, but I seem to have grasped the basics, and it seems like if there is any hope of finding this, it would be to somehow pass the "id" from the post through an FQL query.

Does anyone know of a way to get details of all the photos included in a multi photo feed post?  I'm ok with a dirty workaround with graph or fql if it's the only way.  thanks!  I'm working in iOS/Objective-C by the way.

Comment: A post with multiple photos – what does that even look like? Are you sure it’s not _multiple posts_ containing one photo each, that are just shown grouped together as Facebook does for multiple photos posts that happen within a certain time interval?

Comment: @CBroe it's certainly possible that that's the case.. but i really dont think so... because I see it all the time, ie: 2 pictures of Thing X and a single post message accompanying the 2 photos: "Look at how awesome thing X is!!."... seemingly indicating that the 2 photos were uploaded together for the single post of how awesome thing x is.  But who knows, I could be wrong

Comment: @DanielMcCarthy: Those are "roll-up" posts created by Facebook for display on the user's timeline, and should be ignored by your app. In my experience, there will be individual posts in your feed for each photo uploaded.

Comment: @DanielMcCarthy did you ever figure this out? It's definitely possible to attach more than one photo to a single post. However I've scoured the Graph API reference and stackoverflow trying to figure out how to do this and have come up empty-handed.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I am facing the same problem now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187131/facebook-graph-api-get-post-status-attached-photos

Answer (score 4):

I have answered to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25614053/2274225) containing info on how to do this without FQL since it is deprecated. Even though this is quite an old question I felt like giving an answer for people who might be looking for a solution like mine.