# Facebook graph api v2.1 all post photos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

FQL is deprecated. How i can with graph api get post all photos? Specially for post type link.

Developers documentation said:

/v2.1/{post-id} will now return all photos attached to the post: In previous versions of the API only the first photo was returned with a post. This removes the need to use FQL to get all a post's photos.

But, for example:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=48160623614_10152658744923615&version=v2.1

return only first small photo.

Tnx.

Comment: yep, saw thath and could not figure out what they meant by this. did you find out ?

Comment: no, my project is on stand by because that

Answer (score 0):

I have answered to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25614053/2274225) containing info on how to do this without FQL since it is deprecated. Even though this is quite an old question I felt like giving an answer for people who might be looking for a solution like mine.

I hope that answers your question