# How to get Multiple photos from graph api

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have uploaded 2 photos in web  when Iam parse the feed I am getting only one photo.
In the story property showing 2 photos are there.

```
story = "Vineesh TP added 2 new photos.";
```

How can I get the all photos that I have uploaded.

From the Json Iam getting the response

```
{
    actions =     (
                {
            link = "https://www.facebook.com/100001846436204/posts/758373487567525";
            name = Comment;
        },
                {
            link = "https://www.facebook.com/100001846436204/posts/758373487567525";
            name = Like;
        }
    );
    "created_time" = "2014-10-21T05:55:53+0000";
    from =     {
        id = 100001846436204;
        name = "Vineesh TP";
    };
    icon = "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif";
    id = "100001846436204_758373487567525";
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=758373457567528&set=pcb.758373487567525&type=1&relevant_count=2";
    "object_id" = 758373457567528;
    picture = "https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/10420431_758373457567528_1356675492237188571_n.jpg?oh=4f274cc1e68e7222b98d5db14146d4bf&oe=54BC3A91&__gda__=1424398967_7542f5c26057b6294968d9ef0d67a1bf";
    privacy =     {
        allow = "";
        deny = "";
        description = Public;
        friends = "";
        networks = "";
        value = EVERYONE;
    };
    "status_type" = "mobile_status_update";
    story = "Vineesh TP added 2 new photos.";
    "story_tags" =     {
        0 =         (
                        {
                id = 100001846436204;
                length = 10;
                name = "Vineesh TP";
                offset = 0;
                type = user;
            }
        );
    };
    type = photo;
    "updated_time" = "2014-10-21T05:55:53+0000";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this field

```
?fields=attachments
```

you will get all the photos related to the post.

Answer (score 0):

**Understanding how stories work related to photos**

You might need some clarification to undertand the reason for why.

> story = "Vineesh TP added 2 new photos.";

This story indicates that you have added 2 photos, if not specified which album, these photos were added to the Timeline album, else to the specified one (obviously).

Note that if you comment or like on this story "... added 2 new photos", those comments and likes are going on the album to which the photos were added. There is no story that you can comment or like with the text "added x new photos", this is just some proxy/shortcut entry in your feed/stream that redirects any comment/like/action to the album where the pictures were added to.

Understanding this, you will get a clarification on what you are parsing over there, and why you only get one picture.  Because he gives you just a "tip" of the iceberg about what happened. Now you can tell the user, two new pictures where added, here is ONE of them as a thumbnail. (Imagine you added 10 pictures, he would still give you one, ore maybe a few more, but never all of them).

**How can I get the photos that I have uploaded ?**

Well this shouldn't be that difficult, first remember to which album you posted the pictures. If you didn't specify an album, then they are uploaded by default to the "timeline photos" album.
What you should do is, query the album edge, query the album where the pictures were added to.

Depending on the publish time, or a list of Id's you keep, you can retrieve the added photos.

**How can I get ALL the photos that I have uploaded ?**

- For like ALL ALL pictures -> Check the photos edge of Facebook API
- For like normal pictures that you have upload by default upload actions, query the timeline album

**references**

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/album
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/photo

**Quote from Facebook**

> /v2.1/{post-id} will now return all photos attached to the post In
>   previous versions of the API only the first photo was returned with a
>   post. Any apps that expect only one photo to be returned should
>   upgrade to possible receive more than one.

Comment: good try, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187131/facebook-graph-api-get-post-status-attached-photos/25614053#25614053

Comment: @BalasubramaniM : Well I stand corrected since I have no extensive experience with the v2.1. But you sound rather sarcastic, this is not a competition to know everything ;)